# Fuseki 2 low performance

Tags: performance, sparql, dbpedia, fuseki, tdb

I have stored 80GB triples using FUSEKI 2 (latest version), which is actually a DbPedia dump.  My problem happens when I run the following query. It is taking more than 5 minutes to return whereas at [Snorql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%20%28count%28*%29%20AS%20%3Fx%29%20WHERE%20%20%20%7B%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FFinding_Nemo%3E%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Fr2%20%20.%20%20%3Fr3%20%20%3Fp1%20%20%3Fr2%20%20%7D) it takes less than one second.

```
SELECT  (count(*) AS ?x) WHERE   {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Finding_Nemo>  rdf:type ?r2  .
  ?r3  ?p1  ?r2  
}
```

My machine is 16GB RAM and I guess I am missing some configuration. I fear this query is doing some reasoning in the background. I do appreciate any help.

My configuration file is:

```
@prefix :      <http://base/#> .
    @prefix tdb:   <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
    @prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
    @prefix ja:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
    @prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
    @prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
    :service_tdb_all  a fuseki:Service;rdfs:label"TDB DBPEDIA";fuseki:dataset:tdb_dataset_readwrite;fuseki:name"DBPEDIA";fuseki:serviceQuery"query","sparql";fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore"get";fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore"data";fuseki:serviceUpdate"update";fuseki:serviceUpload"upload".:
tdb_dataset_readwrite
            a tdb:DatasetTDB;tdb:location"apache-jena-fuseki-2.5.0/run/databases/DBPEDIA".
```

Comment: The backend of the DBpedia endpoint is called Virtuoso, not SNORQL.

Comment: How many triples match your query?

Comment: Hi AKSW, thanks. You are correct the DBpedia endpoint is called Virtuoso, not SNORQL. As to the question, I am getting 16158400 triples as a result.